# TinyTDS Undefined symbol dbsetluser

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, freetds, tiny-tds, ruby-enterprise-edition

I've been struggling for the last couple of days with this issue and I'm out of ideas. I am working on a somewhat out of date application, in which I now need to add support for SQL Server. I have managed to get it to work locally (Ubuntu 12.04), but I am running into the following error when trying to reproduce it on Rackspace on a Ubuntu 8.04 instance:

```
irb > require 'rubygems'
irb > require 'tiny_tds'
irb > TinyTds::Client.new(:host => 'X.X.X.X', :user name => 'xxx', :password => 'xxx')
irb: symbol lookup error: /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.0.rc1/lib/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so: undefined symbol: dbsetluser
```

The stack I'm running is:

- Ubuntu 8.04
- REE 1.8.7-2012.02
- FreeTDS 0.92.377 (compiled from source)
- TinyTDS 0.6.0.rc1 (also tried 0.5.1)

I can successfully connect to the SQL Server using isql, which leads me to think that FreeTDS and ODBC is set up correctly. But whenever I try to connect from Ruby with TinyTds, I get the above error.

I have tried posting to the Google group for rails-sqlserver-adapter, but the forum seems moderated and my question has not yet shown up.

I'm fairly certain it has to do with TinyTds not finding the libraries (which I believe should be available somewhere), but I do not know how to achieve this.

As a last resort, I am going to start building a server from scratch with 12.04, but I would much prefer to get the existing system working.

**UPDATE**:

As per @Casper's suggestion I have tried connecting with `odbc` and now I get a different error

```
irb > require ‘odbc’
irb > ODBC.connect('dsn', 'username', 'password')
[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source`
```

even though I can successfully connect with isql and sqsh.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use TinyTDS? I've successfully used FreeTDS in the past with ODBC with the Rails SQLServer Adapter and it works great. So that's the route I would shoot for. Same Ubuntu release here too.

Comment: Thanks @Casper, I tried TinyTds as that is what most of the guides seem to suggest, and I believe is the default for Rails SQL Server Adapter. I have tried connecting with odbc now instead, but still to no avail (see updated content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all had to do with environment variables. It seems like after installing freetds and odbc, the environment variables for `FREETDSCONF`, `ODBCINI` and `ODBCSYSINI` were not made available to Ruby. I had to add them to my user's `.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` as well as in my Apache config in order to get Passenger to see them (using `SetEnv`).

Hope this helps someone in the future.